# Expose random unique port on all pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a deployment that creates pods running a container on a specific port. I am looking to give each pod a unique port and exposing it outside the cluster on that unique port. I tried using a service, but this will create one port for all the pods and act as a load balancer.

deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: name-deployment
  labels:
    app: name
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: name
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: name
      image: image
      ports:
        - containerPort: 25566
```

Comment: What is your use case? What are you trying to achieve by this? If I understand your question correctly, why don't you use three different deployments with one replica each?

Comment: Say I have three pods running, then I want to connect to them from outside the cluster using <node-ip>:30001, <node-ip>:30002, <node-ip>:30003. I would also scale this deployment dynamically so creating many deployments wouldn't make sense as far as I can see. Hope that made it clearer. @KamolHasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible as all pods under one deployment will have same configuration including exposed ports. Creating different deployments and setting custom scaling logic would help you here.